# java : Can't use constructor in array

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor, attributes

I'm a student in java and have a question on how to create an object with attributes in an array.
so this is my empty constructor and constructor with variables to set the attributes

```
public class Punt {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Punt(){

    }

    public void Punt(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }     
}
```

Then i need to make an array of creating objects with x,y and i got this

```
public class Punten {
    private int[] punten = {new Punt(3, 4),
        new Punt(5, 12),
        new Punt(7, 24),
        new Punt(9, 40),
        new Punt(11, 60),
        new Punt(13, 84)
};
```

The error is Punt() in Punt cannot be applied to ( int,     int)
The red line is under the two ints

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Remove `void` from your "constructors", or they are considered as regular methods.

Comment: It's not an `int[]`, it's a `Punt[]`.

Comment: Apply the above 2 changes and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. A constructor does not have a `return type`, so remove `void` from your 2 constructors

   ```
   public Punt(){
   }
   public void Punt(int x, int y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
   ```
2. You are instanciating an array of `Punt` element, not of ints so

   ```
   private Punt[]
   ```